# How to handle when connection pool gets exhausted using snowflake with python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, connection-pooling

can someone explain me how can we handle the situation when the max connections limit has been reached for any database. Can we make a connection in wait state until any existing connection gets released automatically.

```
import snowflake.connector as sf
import sqlalchemy.pool as pool
def get_conn():
    conn = sf.connect(
        user='username',
        password='password',
        account='snowflake-account-name',
        warehouse='compute_wh',
        database='customer_data'
    )

    return conn

mypool = pool.QueuePool(get_conn, max_overflow=10, pool_size=5)
a = mypool.connect()
a1 = mypool.connect()
a2 = mypool.connect()
a3 = mypool.connect()
a4 = mypool.connect()
a5 = mypool.connect()
a6 = mypool.connect()
a7 = mypool.connect()
a8 = mypool.connect()
a9 = mypool.connect() 
a11 = mypool.connect()
a12 = mypool.connect()
a13 = mypool.connect()
a14 = mypool.connect()
a15 = mypool.connect()
```

till a14 we will get 10 connections objects successfully but
when we uncomment and run this a15. we will get an error as pool exhausted.. how to handle this case ??

if we need to write the logic in such a way that we have to give access even
though the instances keep increasing. help me how i can send back the connection
to the pool ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pool is configured to hold five open connections to the database and create up to ten 'overflow' connections for times of heavy load.

Doing `mypool.connect()` will check out a connection, so when you exceed the pool size plus the overflow you get an error.

You should return connections to the pool if you don't need them to do more work.

This can be done explicitly by calling e.g. `a1.close()` (by the way, it would be good to give descriptive names - these are Connection objects).

However, the better way is to use a context manager, because if an exception is thrown between your checking out a connection and returning it with `conn.close()`, you will end up having a permanently checked-out connection and ultimately have the same problem.

e.g.

```py
with mypool.connect() as conn:
    do_some_work(conn)

more_code()
```

When you finish the `with` block (context manager) and move on to more code, or if you exit it with an exception, the connection will be returned to the pool for future use.

Comment: @padding Atlon thanks for the hint you have given to me... I've tried to implement by using with statement.. and succeeded to do it. 
please check my code and help me if i'm wrong...

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will work even if the max limit is reached in pool. Correct me if I did something wrong.

```
import snowflake.connector as sf
import sqlalchemy.pool as pool
    
class Database:
    connection_pool = None
    
    @classmethod
    def initialise(cls):
        def get_conn():
            conn = sf.connect(
                user='username',
                password='password',
                account='accountname',
                warehouse='compute_wh',
                database='customer_data'
            )
    
            return conn
    
        cls.connection_pool = pool.QueuePool(get_conn, max_overflow=1, pool_size=1)
    
class ConnectionFromPool:
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection  = None
        
    def __enter__(self):
        self.connection = Database.connection_pool.connect()
        return self.connection
        
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.connection.commit()
        Database.connection_pool.dispose()
    
    
class User:
    def __init__(self, cust_key, name, address):
        self.cust_key = cust_key
        self.name = name
        self.address = address
    
    def save_to_db(self):
        with ConnectionFromPool() as connection:
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute("insert into data(cust_key,name,address) values (%s, %s, %s)", (self.cust_key, self.name, self.address))
    
    
    
Database.initialise()
user_to_db = User(1,'padma', 'ramnagar')
user_to_db.save_to_db()
user_to_db.save_to_db()
print("success")
```

Comment: It seems very ... intricate. But perhaps I don't understand your use case. As I said in my answer, SQLAlchemy connections can automatically be used in a context manager, so not sure why you need to make your own. I'm also not sure that pool.dispose is what you want (why throw away the pooled connections?) and if you don't want to be bound to a number of connections other than the hard limit of the DB I'm not sure why you want a pool at all?

Comment: @PaddyAlton , first of all. thank you for your concern towards this issue. 

Let us assume that i've mentioned pool_size as 5 and max_overflow limit as 10 for connections and  lets assume we deployed our project. and users try to login into our app. it only allows upto 15 connections for the 16 th person who tries to login would failed, to handle this case. My code is working fine for this now.

Comment: Right - the point of having a pool is to limit how much of the database's resources your application can utilise. If you need more simultaneous connections in practice, you can increase the size of the pool. If you don't want these limits, you can avoid using a pool at all. Anyway, if you want a pool then I think you should change `Database.connection_pool.dispose()` to `self.connection.close()`. This will return the connection to the pool rather than throwing away the pool.

Comment: @PaddyAlton thank you for the help but i'm using Queuepool from sqlalchemy for the connection pool purpose but quuepool class does not have a close() method. it only has a dispose() method to close a connection

Comment: That's right, but the connection which you checked out from the pool does have a `close()` method. Note that my suggestion was to switch `Database.connection_pool.dispose` for `self.connection.close` (where `self` is an instance of `ConnectionFromPool`). This will not actually close the connection, despite the name - it will check the connection back into the pool, ready for reuse. If you don't want that, then in my opinion you don't want a pool at all.

Comment: @PaddyAlton. hello sir. did you ever worked on redis ?? 

i'm facing an issue. Basically in redis we have redis.core and redis-stack.. when i use redis-stack data types to do operations . i'm getting an error as 

127.0.0.1:6379> JSON.SET doc $ '{"a":2}'
(error) ERR unknown command `JSON.SET`, with args beginning with: `doc`, `$`, `{"a":2}`,